# Formatting of lightning-output-field in grid with LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, formatting, outputfield

I'm trying to display 2 columns of data in a LWC using .  They are displaying ok (ideally I would want the labels not wrapping) but when I resize the browser window, some of the columns can jump to the right.

Looking good :-

[image: looking good]

Bottom left field jumps right when browser window made smaller :-

[image: bottom left field jumps right when browser window made smaller]

Middle left field jumps right when browser window made even smaller :-

[image: Middle left field jumps right when browser window made even smaller]

My html looks like

```
<template>
    <template if:true={readmode}>
        <div class="centerButtonDiv">
            <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Update Preferences" onclick={customShowModalPopup}>
            </lightning-button>
        </div>
        <lightning-record-view-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name={ObjectName}>
            
            <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                <div class="slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning-output-field field-name="Preferences_Are_Client_Approved__c"></lightning-output-field><br/>
                    <lightning-output-field field-name="Last_Client_Approval_Given_By__c"></lightning-output-field><br/>
                    <lightning-output-field field-name="Preference_Centre_Visited__c"></lightning-output-field><br/>
                </div>

                <div class="slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning-output-field field-name="Date_of_Last_Client_Approval__c"></lightning-output-field><br/>
                    <lightning-output-field field-name="HasOptedOutOfEmail"></lightning-output-field><br/>
                    <lightning-output-field field-name="Do_not_email__c"></lightning-output-field><br/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </lightning-record-view-form>
    </template>
</template>
```

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `<br/>` here; this causes odd behavior in conjunction with SLDS styles. Each element needs to be in its own layout container:

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-wrap">
    <div class="slds-size_1-of-2">
        <lightning-output-field field-name="Preferences_Are_Client_Approved__c"></lightning-output-field>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-size_1-of-2">
        <lightning-output-field field-name="Date_of_Last_Client_Approval__c"></lightning-output-field>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-size_1-of-2">
        <lightning-output-field field-name="Last_Client_Approval_Given_By__c"></lightning-output-field>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-size_1-of-2">
        <lightning-output-field field-name="HasOptedOutOfEmail"></lightning-output-field>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-size_1-of-2">
        <lightning-output-field field-name="Preference_Centre_Visited__c"></lightning-output-field>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-size_1-of-2">
        <lightning-output-field field-name="Do_not_email__c"></lightning-output-field>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that the default grid goes left to right, so we interleave the left and right columns here.

You can also use `lightning-layout` and `lightning-layout-item` instead of directly using div elements.

```
<lightning-layout multiple-rows>
    <lightning-layout-item size="6">
        <lightning-output-field field-name="Preferences_Are_Client_Approved__c"></lightning-output-field>
    </lightning-layout-item>
    <lightning-layout-item size="6">
        <lightning-output-field field-name="Date_of_Last_Client_Approval__c"></lightning-output-field>
    </lightning-layout-item>
    <lightning-layout-item size="6">
        <lightning-output-field field-name="Last_Client_Approval_Given_By__c"></lightning-output-field>
    </lightning-layout-item>
    <lightning-layout-item size="6">
        <lightning-output-field field-name="HasOptedOutOfEmail"></lightning-output-field>
    </lightning-layout-item>
    <lightning-layout-item size="6">
        <lightning-output-field field-name="Preference_Centre_Visited__c"></lightning-output-field>
    </lightning-layout-item>
    <lightning-layout-item size="6">
        <lightning-output-field field-name="Do_not_email__c"></lightning-output-field>
    </lightning-layout-item>
</lightning-layout>
```

Comment: Thanks sdfcfox, spot on with the <div> solution.  The code was originally without the <br/> but ended up trying many, many different things & must have left them in for my post.  I also tried the <lightning-layout> but that just ended up with one column of 6 items rather than 2 columns of 3 each.  Happy to use <div> though.

Comment: @Stick Yeah, you were just missing `slds-wrap`/`multiple-rows`. Either way works.